# Get coordinates of a certain street to be able to highlight the street in the map view (Here Maps)

Tags: here-api

I'm using the Here Maps JS SDK from a Web Application and I'd like to highlight a certain street. The highlighting itself can be made using a polyline but how do I get the geo coordinates of this street? I looked through the docs of the various HERE Maps REST APIs but couldn't find any solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

To get the geo coordinates of this street you can use our HERE Fleet Telematics API (Data Extension part - PDE) you can read the documentation on https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html

You can get a road geometry from ROAD_GEOM_FCn (where n is 1..5) layer (maybe you need also data from ROAD_ADMIN_FCn,ROAD_NAME_FCn layers), to get description of all layers please see on https://tcs.ext.here.com/pde/maps?url_root=pde.api.here.com

The example request could be like: [PDE request example](https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/tiles.json?apikey=YOUR_API&layers=ROAD_ADMIN_FC5%2CROAD_ADMIN_FC2%2CROAD_ADMIN_FC3%2CROAD_ADMIN_FC4%2CROAD_GEOM_FC5%2CROAD_GEOM_FC2%2CROAD_GEOM_FC3%2CROAD_GEOM_FC4%2CROAD_NAME_FC5%2CROAD_NAME_FC2%2CROAD_NAME_FC3%2CROAD_NAME_FC4%2CLINK_FC5%2CLINK_FC2%2CLINK_FC3%2CLINK_FC4&levels=13%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C13%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C13%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C13%2C10%2C11%2C12&tilexy=8598%2C6376%2C1074%2C797%2C2149%2C1594%2C4299%2C3188%2C8598%2C6376%2C1074%2C797%2C2149%2C1594%2C4299%2C3188%2C8598%2C6376%2C1074%2C797%2C2149%2C1594%2C4299%2C3188%2C8598%2C6376%2C1074%2C797%2C2149%2C1594%2C4299%2C3188&meta=1)

You can compute the tile ID(tilexy) for a given coordinate and layer as follows:

```
      tile size = 180° /2level [degree]
      tileY = trunc((latitude + 90°) / tile size)
      tileX = trunc((longitude + 180°) / tile size)
```

See please examples code on:

https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3.1/pde_street_details

https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/pde_street_details

Comment: links no longer work

maybe a python example would help?